# Can I update my UI on flutter app without changing the backend functions?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I want to know whether its possible to change or update my UI on flutter app without changing anything in the backend. That means like all the widgets, text boxes, buttons, icons stay, just the styling changes. If I change the styling does that require me to change the backend as well in anyway or just update the frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not add/modify any functionalities that need to communicate with the backend, you can make all the change you want.

Actions like; adding padding, switching colour, ... will never require an update of your backend.

You should really apprehend your mobile app and your server as two separate entities. The only bridge between them being the internet :)